# How to perform pagination on MongoDB with spring?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, pagination

I have this java code that gets a list of items from the MongoDB using spring framework:

```
    @Autowired
    private PersonsRepository personsRepository;
     ...
     ...


                         // the name field is NOT INDEXED!
    List<Person> dbRecords = personsRepository.findByName("John");
    for (Person person: dbRecords) {
           //do something
    }
```

The field I need to query is NOT indexed and this can't be changed in the near future.

As the db contains 100s million of records, and the ouput list is expected to contain 10s millions of records, I have few problems:

1. The query itselft (*getByName*) takes alot of time (after several hours it didn't finished). How can I do it better?
2. How can I query with pagination the data?

Thanks

Comment: It's kind of stupid to query a collection with 100s of millions of records without proper indexing... If you can't even create an index, then there is no reason to even bring up topics as sharding because you probably can't change that either then.

Comment: Have you tried using `Pageable`?

Answer (score 0):

So it seems like I found how to use pagination:

I added a new methods to the interface:

```
Page<Person> findByName(@Param("name") String name, Pageable pageable);
```

And in the code itself I did:

```
    Page<Person> nextPage;
    List<Person> dbRecords;
    boolean stop = false;
    Sort sort = new Sort(new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.ASC, SORT_FIELD));
    do {
        Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(0, PAGE_SIZE, sort);
        nextPage = personsRepository.findByName("john", pageable);           
        dbRecords = nextPage.getContent();
        if (dbRecords.size() > 0) {
            // do something
        } else {
            stop = true;
        }
    } while (nextPage.getSize() > 0 && !stop);
```

And now it is working ok with the pagination.